# virtual keyboard wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, keyboard

I am developing a WPF application that will need to a virtual keyboard .
In addition, the application contains windows that need only numeric keyboard and other windows needed the hole keyboard (26 lettres + 10 numbers).
I don't know if there is a tool that can do it or i must design my own keyboard.

What is the best tool to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im using this http://wpfkb.codeplex.com/ and its works fine for me. You can modify it after needs..

Answer (score 5):

> What is the best tool to accomplish this task?

Don't know whether its the best tool, but this one has [The Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl.html) and should do for your needs:

[A Software Virtual Keyboard for Your WPF-Apps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145579/A-Software-Virtual-Keyboard-for-Your-WPF-Apps)

Other answer suggests: [WPF Touch Screen Keyboard](http://wpfkb.codeplex.com/) which has the same license, note the last release is from 2009.